# Getting Alert that Backup Log Failed but it didn't

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm migrating databases from SQL Server 2008 R2 to a new server running SQL Server 2012.  I set up an alert for any severity >= 16.  I have a maintenance plan that includes a log backup of all user databases every 5 minutes.  After restoring about 10 databases to the new server, I started getting an alert every 30 minutes that says:

DESCRIPTION:    BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP LOG *MyDatabaseName*. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

COMMENT:        (None)

JOB RUN:        (None)

I searched the logs and there is nothing about a failed backup, and all the backups are fine.  I get the alert every 30 minutes, so it's not happening on all of the log backups because they run every 5 minutes.  And it's only for one or sometimes two databases out of the 10 that have been restored onto the new server.

I would greatly appreciate anyone that can point me in the right direction to start troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintenance plan runs via a SQL Server Agent job.  Check the history of the job.  Any failures might show there.

Error level 16 is not considered critical and can be fixed by the user.

Just setup the following to monitor all alerts > level 11.

1 - Database mail

http://craftydba.com/?p=1025

2 - Operator

http://craftydba.com/?p=1085

3 - Alerts

http://craftydba.com/?p=1099

Next time you get a alert, you should get an email with details.

If you want to be real fancy, you can have the alert call a job.  Log the alert in the APPLICATION log and then send the email.